# What Can I Use Besides usleep in a Modern POSIX Environment?

Tags: c, posix, c99

I'm fairly new to C but writing a small multithreaded application.  I want to introduce a delay to a thread.  I'd been using 'usleep' and the behavior is what I desire - but it generates warnings in C99.

> implicit declaration of function ‘usleep’

It's only a warning, but it bothers me.  I've Googled for an answer but all I could find was a while-loop / timer approach that seemed like it would be CPU intensive.

EDIT:

My includes are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
```

And I'm invoking the compiler with:

```
c99 program.c -Wall -pedantic -W -lpthread
```

EDIT #2:

I've created a new file that contains:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    usleep(10);
}
```

And I still get the warning.

EDIT #3:
As suggested, I've updated the text of the question.

Comment: Your question has not much to do with C99. Such things are out of the scope of its definitions. Perhaps could you change the title by substituting it for "POSIX".

Comment: Using sleep for thread synchronization smells fishy. Perhaps you would like to use any kind of mutex or signal?

Comment: @eyaim - I am using a mutex and the pthreads library.  I was trying to use usleep to slow down the output generated so it appears 'quazi' real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a standard C99 compiler, but you're trying to access POSIX extensions. To expose the POSIX extensions you should for example define _POSIX_C_SOURCE to 200809L (for the current standard). For example this program:

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
        struct timespec reqtime;
        reqtime.tv_sec = 1;
        reqtime.tv_nsec = 500000000;
        nanosleep(&reqtime, NULL);
}
```

will compile correctly and wait for 1.5 seconds (1 second + 500000000 nanoseconds) with the following compilation command:

```
c99 main.c -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

The _POSIX_C_SOURCE macro must be defined with an appropriate value for the POSIX extensions to be available.

Also the options -Wall, -pedantic and -W are not defined for the POSIX c99 command, those look more like gcc commands to me (if they work on your system then that's fine, just be aware that they are not portable to other POSIX systems).

Answer (score 4):

You are probably on a modern POSIX system:

> POSIX.1-2008  removes  the  specification  of     usleep().

On my system (linux) there is a detailed explanation of the macros that must be set to get that function back. But you should just follow the advice that zvrba already gave, use `nanosleep` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  Yes - I am on a modern POSIX system.  This seems to explain why usleep() results in the warning....but I seem to get an identical error if I use nanosleep, regardless of what header files I include.

Comment: Add at the top of your source files `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or on the compiler command line `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual page: This function is obsolete. Use nanosleep instead.

Comment: Nanosleep yields the same warning.  Sleep, seems to work, but it only accepts seconds as an input.

Comment: You need to include the appropriate header file. All of this is written in the documentation.

Comment: Even more "POSIX.1-2008  removes  the  specification  of
       usleep()."

Comment: @zvrba - I have included all the header files I'm using in the question text.  None of them seem to help.  The documentation I'm looking at says Nanosleep is defined in time.h (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_nanosleep.htm) but the warning remains.

Comment: @RobP. Note that nanosleep requires `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 0):

> implicit declaration of function ‘usleep’

This warning usually means that you didn't `#include` the right header file, in this case [`unistd.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the `#include <unistd.h>` ?.

And you can use some of the similar methods instead: nanosleep() for nanoseconds and sleep() for seconds. Or another way could be using clock(), but i think this is more CPU wasting.